# Rails trying to load assets from incorrect locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I'm having a problem with my javascript and jquery.  I'm using bootstrap in addition to some self written scripts.  When I attempt a javascript driven action (i.e. clicking a button that shows a hidden div, or openning a modal), the browser does not respond.  The browser's javascript console shows the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/ecns/css/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/ecns/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Notice that the location is in the folder "ecns" rather than "assets".  Ecns is one of my models, the one I currently was working with in my browser, if I go to a different part of my app, the error looks like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/requests/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

I know there is not a problem with the scripts themselves because they work on different computers.  I'm assuming I have something in rails either configured or installed incorrectly.  For reference, here is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And the following is in my application layout:

```
<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <title>Site</title>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
...
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Why would rails be looking to the incorrect locations for the assets? I'm running rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is using a custom asset pipeline, that will make all the assets visible under the `assets` subdirectory in the root directory of the app.

So if your base address is `http://www.something.com/` all assets will live under `http://www.something.com/assets/`.

If you want to import a CSS or a JS file, and if you placed them correctly in the `app/assets/` directory in Rails, you should use these commands:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap.min" %>
```

Placing them wherever you need in your layout.

If you still want to import them manually (and I'd not recommend it), use these:

```
<script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: I added the two lines <%= java.... and <%= stylesh.... and deleted my script line from my application layout, but I still get an error for my css: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/ecns/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Something is going wrong here, since it seems to be still loading the old css. Have you already tried restarting the server? Moreover, are you sure you removed *all* those kind of manual imports?

Comment: Ah, you are correct, I missed deleting the stylesheet link.  Perfect! Thank you very much!